# Rails 3 Routes with or without :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is there a way to have a route allow an `:id` or a `nil`?

For example:

```
match 'product_specs/:id' => 'home#product_specs', 
      :as => :product_specs, 
      :via => :get
```

takes the `id` as a param. But I'd also like to pass an empty param like this `product_specs_path()` so that I can also have the option of loading all my records.

Is there a routes match that can achieve this?

Comment: isn't this just generally the difference between index and show? product_specs_path vs product_specs_path(@product)

Comment: these are results loading in modal windows and there are many different actions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

perhaps if you use the optional parameter as

```
# Routes
match 'product_specs/(:id)' => 'home#product_specs'

# Controller
def product_specs
  if params[:id].nil?
    product_specs = ProductSpecs.all()
  else
    product_specs = ProductSpecs.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Would something like that work?